# Custom label for chemical structures

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, chemfig

I need a custom label for my chemical structures and everything works fine but the label isn't centered. Does anyone know how to center the label?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{chem}
\addtocounter{chem}{1}
\newcommand{\chemlabel}[1]{%
  \hypertarget{#1}{\textbf{\number\value{chem}}}
   \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel {#1}
   {{\number\value{chem}}{\thepage}{\number\value{chem}}{#1}{}}}% 
  \refstepcounter{chem} 
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{Benzen}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen1}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen2}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen3}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some `%` at the end of lines in your definition of `\chemlabel` otherwise the ends of lines appear as spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{chem}
\addtocounter{chem}{1}
\newcommand{\chemlabel}[1]{%
  \hypertarget{#1}{\textbf{\number\value{chem}}}% <<<<
   \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel {#1}
   {{\number\value{chem}}{\thepage}{\number\value{chem}}{#1}{}}}% 
  \refstepcounter{chem}% <<<<
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{Benzen}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen1}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen2}}
\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)}}{\chemlabel{str:benzen3}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: do you know [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum)?

Comment: Why simple when you can make it even hard. I didn't know the chemnum-package but thank you very much!